# Find coefficients (linear regression) for sum over two variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, coefficients

I am trying to find the coefficients for a linear regression given some data.

The following R code gives the coefficients:

```
m8 <- lm(T ~ X + Y, A)
summary(m8)
```

I would now like to include one coefficient for the sum over X and Y:

```
m9 <- lm(T ~ X + Y + (X+Y), A)
summary(m9)
```

Unfortunately R does not include an additional coefficient here. Is there an easy way to obtain a coefficient for (X+Y)?

Comment: You could create a separate variable ahead of time (say, Z), and then change the formula to `X + Y + Z`. However, there will be a correlation of 1 between that predictor and the other two, so I don't see how that will help the model.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `+` operator means different things inside formula syntax than it does when it is used as R function (like in `x <- a + b`).

Hope this answers your question (short answer is to use `I()` to compute variables on the fly within formula syntax):

```r
df <- mtcars

# They get dropped as they are fully redundant predictors   
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + (disp + hp), data = df)  
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + disp + hp, data = df) 

summary(mod1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp + (disp + hp), data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.7945 -2.3036 -0.8246  1.8582  6.9363 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 30.735904   1.331566  23.083  < 2e-16 ***
#> disp        -0.030346   0.007405  -4.098 0.000306 ***
#> hp          -0.024840   0.013385  -1.856 0.073679 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.127 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7482, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7309 
#> F-statistic: 43.09 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.062e-09

# They are identical, only formula is different
all.equal(summary(mod1), summary(mod2), use.names = FALSE)
#> [1] "Component 1: target, current do not match when deparsed"
#> [2] "Component 2: formulas differ in contents"
```

If you want to compute variables on the fly inside formula use `I()`:

```r
# If you want to define variables on the fly inside formula use I()
# It gives NA estimates as the sum is a liniar combination of predictors, i.e. no useful variance
mod3 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + I(disp + hp), data = df)  
summary(mod3)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp + I(disp + hp), data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.7945 -2.3036 -0.8246  1.8582  6.9363 
#> 
#> Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  30.735904   1.331566  23.083  < 2e-16 ***
#> disp         -0.030346   0.007405  -4.098 0.000306 ***
#> hp           -0.024840   0.013385  -1.856 0.073679 .  
#> I(disp + hp)        NA         NA      NA       NA    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.127 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7482, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7309 
#> F-statistic: 43.09 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.062e-09

# Another example using I() with an interaction therm, i.e. the product of predictors
# Product is disp * hp is not a liniar combination of predictors
mod4 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + I(disp * hp), data = df) 
summary(mod4)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp + I(disp * hp), data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.5153 -1.6315 -0.6346  0.9038  5.7030 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   3.967e+01  2.914e+00  13.614 7.18e-14 ***
#> disp         -7.337e-02  1.439e-02  -5.100 2.11e-05 ***
#> hp           -9.789e-02  2.474e-02  -3.956 0.000473 ***
#> I(disp * hp)  2.900e-04  8.694e-05   3.336 0.002407 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.692 on 28 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8198, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8005 
#> F-statistic: 42.48 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.499e-10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Nevertheless, a sum of predictors is always redundant in linear models as all the useful variance is already provided by the predictors themselves and the sum brings nothing new (it is just a liniar combination, i.e. full multicollinearity).